# I have to prove a vector operation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

I have to prove
$$\nabla^2 \log r = \frac{1}{r^2} $$

Can I do in this way: 
$$\nabla^2 \log r = \frac{\partial^2 { \log r}}{\partial r^2} = \frac{\partial{ 1/r}}{\partial r} = - \frac{1}{ r^2}  $$

I think I am doing in the wrong way so I got a minus sign.
 [I can solve it by elaborate way but I just want to know  how the short way I did is wrong ]

Comment: Look up the Laplacian $\nabla^2$ in polar coordinates. Your calculation assumes an incorrect form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incorrect expression for the divergence operator: in $n$ dimensions, the Laplacian of a radial function should actually be
$$ \nabla^2 f(r) = \operatorname{div} \operatorname{grad} f(r) =  \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^{n-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f(r) \right). $$
This gives
$$ \nabla^2 \log{r} = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^{n-2} \right) = \frac{n-2}{r^2}, $$
and taking $n=3$ gives the result you want.